# Calculate distance to nearest train station

Tags: web-browser, maps

When **researching property, I would like to know how far from a train station they are**, as the distance could be a deal-breaker.

The real estate websites I use only have a basic map, therefore I have to **copy/paste the property address into google/bing maps, figure out the nearest station, then choose "get directions"** to that station and note the walking distance.

Challenges include:

- Since I'm looking in many different suburbs, I have no idea which train station would be nearest
- If I hit "Get Directions" in Google Maps, it defaults to directions to my current location (so I have to then edit it and type in the nearest train station that I've found by eye)
- Google Maps seems to think tram stops qualify as train stations
- I've also tried manipulating the URL/search string, with no success
- I've also tried Bing Maps and others, none of them seem to understand what "nearest train station" is

Does anyone know a quicker/easier way?

Ideally the solution would be a website (or utilise one). Alternatively Windows software would be acceptable.

Comment: Please note this site is about recommending software meeting specific requirements – not approaches, [languages](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/36/185), [technologies](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2451/185) or [algorithms](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/865/185). In case you wanted to ask for software: What OS should it run on, what is your price margin, [etc](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185)?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in Google Maps.

Click the station so it gives you the 'location bubble' then in the sidebar click the 'navigate' button.
Then just click on the property location.

It will route.

Two fairly random locations chosen in North London…

[image]

<sup>there are no trams in North London, so idk how it handles those</sup>